# UINavigationController push view and show toolbar has strange toolbar animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a  `UINavigationController` which is inside of a `UITabBarController`.  In my nav controller, I want to show the `toolbar` when I push a view, effectively hiding the tab bar at the same time.  It "works", but the toolbar animates up from the bottom, rather than doing a smooth slide in transition.

Added to my first view:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Why is the `toolbar` animating up from the bottom?  Shouldn't it slide in so the transition between sliding out the `tabbar` and in with the `toolbar` can be seemless?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set toolbar show or hide in `– navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` of `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't even have a delegate. What should I make the delegate of the navigation controller?